# Amplify precedence of commands

Tags: macros

Have been using `\setlength\bigskipamount{#1}`.  But I want to amplify precedence like this.  Is this correct or should {#1} be put inside the braces of `\bigskipamount` ?

```
\setlength{\bigskipamount}{#1}
```

Comment: why don't you try it out?

Comment: Both work. But I have no idea what "amplify precedence" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Means making the command clearer that `\bigskipamount` is argument to `\setlength`

Comment: `\setlength{\lengthname}{value_in_specified_unit}`.  Otherwise I can use spaces between arguments `\setlength \lengthname #1`.

Comment: Looks there is no precedence, just `\setlength` taking two arguments.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't be changing the value of `\bigskipamount`. 2. “Amplify precedence” means nothing. Please note that continuing to ask questions that earn downvotes can lead to ban you from asking questions for a while.

Comment: I shall move to the mountains as an outcast of society.  Then come to me for advice and I will tell you everything. Be blessed my child.

Comment: Should `\bigskipamount` be always kept constant ?

Comment: It should be kept the same for the document. Similarly for `\smallskipamount` and `\medskipamount`. The appropriate value depends on the font size and it shouldn't be a rigid length. It includes both positive and negative stretchiness. Since LaTeX uses it for various purposes, changing it will lead to unexpected and inconsistent results.

Comment: why do you describe braces around bigskipamount as putting {#1} inside braces, your question is not clear at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the question means 'can I place braces around material here'. Answering from two perspectives:

### The Lamport Position

In Lamport's book which defines the core LaTeX commands, *all* arguments are given in braces. As such, they are always 'allowed' when dealing with document commands.

### The TeXnical answer

The `\setlength` macro requires two arguments: the first *must* be a single token, the second may comprise multiple tokens. When TeX looks for an undelimited argument (as here) and grabs a braced group ('balanced text'), the consumer macro receives the material without the braces. As such, giving `{\foo}` or `\foo` both end up with the macro grabbing these tokens getting exactly the same result: `\foo`.

Also, whilst not asked directly, be aware that TeX skips spaces after control sequences. Thus `\foo \bar` and `\foo\bar` are the same.

Comment: How does Latex determine which arguments belong to which commands ?  Is it something I should be careful about ?

Comment: @Veak \setlength is defined as `\def\setlength#1#2{...}`, so it takes two arguments.

Comment: @Veak At the TeX level, you can always `\show` a macro, but conceptually this won't always match up. For example, `\def\foo#1{\fooa{#1}}\def\fooa#1#2{...}`: technically `\foo` takes one argument but conceptually it takes two. That shows up most obviously with document commands: things like optional arguments have non-trivial code setup. So 'read the docs' if you are not sure about a given command is the best advice we can give.